# How do get dimensions of elements in Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm running my react native application in the xcode simulator. Now I would like to check for the dimensions of the elements and if possible I would like to change things temporarily to see, what I have to change in my code. Something like the developer tools in the chrome browser. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `react-devtools` for this (see [guide in official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#react-developer-tools)).

When the developer tools are installed and running, you can use the regular Element inspector debug tool from the React Native developer menu (`Cmd`+`D`, `Show Inspector`).

Now, instead of limited the in-simulator inspector, you have access to a Chrome Devtools like experience, where you can inspect and edit element styles and props.

[image: Devtools example]

Answer (score 0):

Use Xcode to build the app and run in simulator, and then you can use the [debugging view hierarchy tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html)